# Elasticsearch index mapper

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I'm trying to figure out how the mapping work but can't get it right, I copied the logstash template to be used as my custom index name. However I'm getting the following issue:

```
    MapperParsingException[failed to parse [data]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[unknown property [customerId]];
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.FieldMapper.parse(FieldMapper.java:329)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseObjectOrField(DocumentParser.java:311)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseObject(DocumentParser.java:328)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseObject(DocumentParser.java:254)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseDocument(DocumentParser.java:124)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:309)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.prepareCreate(IndexShard.java:533)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.prepareCreateOnPrimary(IndexShard.java:510)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.prepareIndexOperationOnPrimary(TransportIndexAction.java:214)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.executeIndexRequestOnPrimary(TransportIndexAction.java:223)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportShardBulkAction.shardIndexOperation(TransportShardBulkAction.java:327)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportShardBulkAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportShardBulkAction.java:120)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportShardBulkAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportShardBulkAction.java:68)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$PrimaryPhase.doRun(TransportReplicationAction.java:657)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$PrimaryOperationTransportHandler.messageReceived(TransportReplicationAction.java:287)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$PrimaryOperationTransportHandler.messageReceived(TransportReplicationAction.java:279)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.RequestHandlerRegistry.processMessageReceived(RequestHandlerRegistry.java:77)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$4.doRun(TransportService.java:378)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown property [customerId]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.StringFieldMapper.parseCreateFieldForString(StringFieldMapper.java:371)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.StringFieldMapper.parseCreateField(StringFieldMapper.java:320)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.FieldMapper.parse(FieldMapper.java:321)
    ... 22 more
```

I tried to ignore the data field which is actually an object so it will be processed and saved as raw string, below is the mapping template that I'm attempting to use.

```
{
  "order": 0,
  "template": "sl-prod-*",
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "refresh_interval": "5s"
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "message_field": {
            "mapping": {
              "fielddata": {
                "format": "disabled"
              },
              "index": "analyzed",
              "omit_norms": true,
              "type": "string"
            },
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "match": "message"
          }
        },
        {
          "string_fields": {
            "mapping": {
              "fielddata": {
                "format": "disabled"
              },
              "index": "analyzed",
              "omit_norms": true,
              "type": "string",
              "fields": {
                "raw": {
                  "ignore_above": 256,
                  "index": "not_analyzed",
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "data": {
                  "ignore_above": 256,
                  "index": "not_analyzed",
                  "type": "string"
                }
              }
            },
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "match": "*"
          }
        }
      ],
      "_all": {
        "omit_norms": true,
        "enabled": true
      },
      "properties": {
        "msg": {
          "index": "not_analyzed",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "@timestamp": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "geoip": {
          "dynamic": true,
          "properties": {
            "ip": {
              "type": "ip"
            },
            "latitude": {
              "type": "float"
            },
            "location": {
              "type": "geo_point"
            },
            "longitude": {
              "type": "float"
            }
          }
        },
        "data": {
          "index": "not_analyzed",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "@version": {
          "index": "not_analyzed",
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aliases": {}
}
```

Any help will be appreciated ...

Answer (score 0):

In your mapping, 'data' is a string that does not contain a customerID property.

See here for a similar issue: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/5084

Comment: I'm not trying to parse the customerID. So how I would enforce "data" from the creation of the index to be string on the mapping level, so it will never attempt to parse it as object?

Comment: I don't know if there's a way to bypass reading that. It may be easier to just add properties to that string_fields mapping data object.